# Inserting a sub-array into a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

The following statement inserts part of an array into an empty vector. It then prints the last elemnt inserted which is 14 in this case. My question is, how is the final array element that is inserted being determined with this syntax? How is "myArray+3" returning the third element in the array to the function?

```
vector <int> myVector(10);

    int myArray[5] = {3,9,14,19,94};

    myVector.insert(myVector.begin(), myArray, myArray+3);
    cout << myVector.at(2) << endl;
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the basics of C++? Pointer arithmetic?

Comment: That's a nice try, but unfortunately, that's not how memory works

Comment: This question as it is now is too broad as it asks us to explain pointer arithmetic.

Comment: where did you get the code?

Comment: If you find yourself frequently inserting at the start of a `vector`, consider using a `deque`.

Comment: _"How is "myArray+3" returning the third element in the array to the function?"_ It isn't returning the 3rd element, but points one beyond the 3rd element in your `myArray`. Also there's no need to preallocate the vector (`vector <int> myVector(10);`) if you use `insert()`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you surprised that it prints 14 and expect something else?

Comment: @tobi303 he got it from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert (last example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the vector is not empty. It has 10 elements initialized by zeroes.

```
vector <int> myVector(10);
```

As for these arguments

```
myArray, myArray+3
```

then they specify a range in the array the following way

```
[&myArray[0], &myArray[3])
^^^                     ^^^
```

That means that the elements pointed to by these pointers

```
&myArray[0], &myArray[1], &myArray[2]
```

will be included in the vector. That is the second value of the range specifies elements before the value.

The element pointed to by the pointer `&myArray[3]` (that is by the pointer `myArray + 3`) will not be inserted to the vector.

Compare for example. If an array has N elements then the range of acceptable indices for its element is

```
 [0, N-1] 
^^^    ^^^
```

that can be also specified like

```
 [0, N) 
^^^  ^^^
```

Answer (score -5):

Arrays in C++ are laid out in a contiguous fashion, so that the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array, followed by the address of the next, and the next, etc.

Now when you do `myArray + 3`, this is actually saying, "Go to the first element and get the third element from the start position".

So if you had done `(myArray + 1) + 3`, this will mean to first from the first position to the second, and using your new position as a reference point, move three positions from there.

How does it know where to go? Simply by taking the size in bytes of a single element of the array and multiplying that by the distance you wanted to move forward, and then adding this value to the address of the reference position, and voila! You have gotten to the nth element of the array.

Comment: The OP already does when they want. [They use the API correctly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

Comment: `Arrays in C++ are arrayed...nah Jk.` what were you trying?

Comment: @Yashas, no idea what you mean

Comment: I was asking what you were trying to convey by that. Was it supposed to be a joke?